# Mount Laravel Storage on demand (connect to FTP)

Tags: laravel, ftp

I was wondering if Laravel offers the ability to mount an ftp / sftp client on demand.
Let's say you have an application that needs to connect to different FTP clients, based on the customer etcetera? These can change every time.
So you don't want to store them in the `filesystem.php`. What is the best approach for this?

Comment: Store your configurations in .env

Comment: Is there a way to change the .env file when the application is running? Else it would not solve the problem?

Comment: Do you mean dynamically or manually

Comment: Dynamicly (let's say an end user could add ftp settings in his account. Those settings are stored in a database and if the application need to connect to some ftp. It's looks into the database, select the settings from one ftp server and connects to the ftp server based on what the user added to their account / setting table etc. I know how to get the ftp settings from the database, but not how to use those settings to connect / mount an ftp connection)

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 8, you can use Laravel's On-Demand Disks

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#on-demand-disks